# change row font-type using checkboxcolumn datagridview1

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

i build a project successfully using **VB.Net 2012** but now i have one problem that 
i want to change **ROW** font-type (Strikeout) if Checkboxcolumn is clicked
and the other rows is normal font type (Regular)

i think the event is **Table1DataGridView_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged**
but how to code my problem ?

my Checkboxcolumn code is

```
For x As Integer = Table1DataGridView.Rows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If Table1DataGridView.Rows(x).Cells("DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn1").Value Then
                Me.Table1DataGridView.Rows(x).Cells(x).Style.Font = New System.Drawing.Font(My.Settings.ftype, My.Settings.fsize, FontStyle.Strikeout)
            End If
        Next
```

it dosnt work for all Rows just for 1 row only :(

Comment: One minor suggestion for improvement; try `For each x as DataGridviewRow in Table1DataGridview.Rows`, then there's no need for an incrementing counter.

Comment: @JonathonCowley-Thom `For Each` is not an improved version of `For`, just a different alternative which might be more useful in certain situations (but also less useful in other ones). If the OP's loop does perform exactly what he wants (honestly, not 100% sure), indices would be required and consequently a `For` loop would certainly be the best option. Otherwise, how would you know the `x` values? (used not just in `Rows`, but also in `Cells`).

Comment: `x.index`, problem solved.  In stead of `If Table1DataGridView.Rows(x).Cells("DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn1").Value Then`, he could (and I believe should) use `If x.Cells("DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn1").Value Then`

Comment: @MrB, can you please clarify why you are using `Cells(x)`?  X is incrementing on each iteration of the loop.  Is this intentional?

Comment: @JonathonCowley-Thom you mean `givenRow.Index`. But then you would be using indices anyway (why not relying on `x` as the OP does?). My point is that `For Each` is not always better.

Comment: @MrB `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` is not the kind of event which you should use as much as possible and it doesn't seem required here. You just need to perform the actions when the value in a cell has changed and this is delivered by other events, like `CellValueChanged`. You wouldn't need a loop there, just changing the cell you want (defined on account of the cell whose value has been currently modified).

Comment: @JonathonCowley-Thom iam using Cell(X) to detect which row iam work with and i did do the **for each** and i comes up with this code 

`For Each x As DataGridViewRow In Table1DataGridView.Rows
            If Table1DataGridView.Rows(x).Cells("DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn1").Value Then
                Me.Table1DataGridView.Rows(x).Cells.Style.Font = New System.Drawing.Font(My.Settings.ftype, My.Settings.fsize, FontStyle.Strikeout)
            End If
        Next`

Comment: but the error now is how to detect the row that iam working with

'Error 1 Value of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow' cannot be converted to 'Integer'.
'

Comment: I'm suggesting using a For Each because then you'll already have the row, making `Me.Table1Datagridview.Rows(x)` completely unnecessary.  Of course your original code wouldn't work.  The real issue here though is that `Cells(x)` does not work.  You're basically asking for `Cells(RowIndex)`, and the row index is incrementing with every iteration of the loop.  You need to know the `Cell.ColumnIndex` of the cell you're targeting.

Comment: @varocarbas u mean i do the code with the **CellValueChanged** event ? insisted of iam using ?

Comment: I mean that you add the `CellValueChanged event`; it will be reached every time a cell is changed (you can get its row/column from the `e` argument); there you can change the cell you want. Do you get the idea or shall I write a sample code? In any case, note that the ideal event would depend upon your exact conditions, with a checkbox column, it might be better `CellClick` or `CellContentClick`; there are many options.

Comment: However, varocarbas is right about the event you're using being not an ideal choice.

Comment: @varocarbas can u write a simple code of using 'e' argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have 2 columns, the first one is a `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`. Every time a cell in the first column is clicked, the font in the corresponding row of the second column is changed as shown in the description. For this situation, the `CellContentClick` event behaves quite well. Sample code:

```
  Private Sub Table1DataGridView_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles Table1DataGridView.CellContentClick

     Dim curRow = e.RowIndex
     Dim curCol = e.ColumnIndex

     If curRow >= 0 And curCol = 0 Then
         Table1DataGridView.Rows(curRow).Cells(1).Style.Font = New System.Drawing.Font(My.Settings.ftype, My.Settings.fsize, FontStyle.Strikeout)
     End If

 End Sub
```

Comment: i have 4 columns **id**,**mylist**,**checkbox** and **date** 
iam now try to modified your code

Comment: @MrB OK. You can modify my code as much as you wish. I hope that you will understand the exact point of my contribution here: you are asking about the way to modify certain cells on account of certain conditions and I have explained you how to do it. The code I wrote is just a way to ease your understanding (and the one of future readers).

Comment: thanx so much for the help i now understand what its happening in my case 'curCol = 3' because the DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn is on the 3rd Column